# Converting English digits to Bengali digits and make them calculate in a calculator

Tags: android

I have been trying to make Bengali Calculator in Android Studio. I have included the codes and screenshots of the app. My codes works fine with integer values. Whenever i do this code my calculator works fine. (i.e `Integer.parseInt((eresult.getText().toString()));`)
e.g `firstvalue = Integer.parseInt((eresult.getText().toString()));`It can convert English number symbols to Bengali number symbols. But when i use `float` or     `double` it says:

> unfortunately application stopped

(e.g `firstvalue = Double.parseDouble(eresult.getText().toString());` )
How can I use `double` or `float` values in calculator app. Thank you

[image: Screeshot of the app]

This code works fine.

```
else if (v.getId() == R.id.plus) {
        firstvalue = Integer.parseInt((eresult.getText().toString()));
        op = '+';
        eresult.setText("");
    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.minus) {
        firstvalue = Integer.parseInt(eresult.getText().toString());
        op = '-';
        eresult.setText("");
    }
    .
    .
    . 
     else if (v.getId() == R.id.equal) {
        secondvalue = Integer.parseInt(eresult.getText().toString());
        switch (op) {
            case '+':
                result = (firstvalue + secondvalue);
                eresult.setText(BengaliConvert(result+""));

                break;
                .
                .
                .
```

when i do this below code it doesn't work. App stops when i enter firstvalue then (+,-,*,/) sign.

```
 else if (v.getId() == R.id.plus) {
        firstvalue = Double.parseDouble((eresult.getText().toString()));
        op = '+';
        eresult.setText("");
 .
 .
 .
 else if (v.getId() == R.id.equal) {
        secondvalue = Double.parseDouble(eresult.getText().toString());
        switch (op) {
            case '+':
                result = (firstvalue + secondvalue);
                eresult.setText(BengaliConvert(result + ""));
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I think you can simplify this example a bit to make it easier to diagnose the problem. Where exactly in the code is the exception being thrown? Can you write the minimum test that replicates the issue?

Comment: firstvalue = Double.parseDouble(eresult.getText().toString());


secondvalue = Double.parseDouble(eresult.getText().toString());

 instead of it if i use 

 int firstvalue;
int secondvalue;

int result;

firstvalue = Integer.parseInt(eresult.getText().toString());
secondvalue =Integer.parseInt(eresult.getText().toString());
 
it works,,while it doesn't works when i use parseDouble for
 
double firstvalue;
double secondvalue;

Comment: So please [edit] the question to make the example as small as possible. What code works, what doesn't work, what are the expected results?

Comment: I have edited the question. Please take a look

Comment: Okay that's better. But shouldn't you be using your `BengaliConvert` before you try `parseDouble`? So something like `secondValue = Double.parseDouble(BengaliConvert(eresult.getText().toString())`

Comment: as  u can convert English digits into bangla then just try to make an english version calculator ... then when all done, just just show the converted value ..

Comment: still it doesn't work :(